# how do url rewriting in asp.net mvc i want to show different url name instead of actual one

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, routes

i have url called http://0.00.000.000:0000/ics/Account/Login but i want to show the fixed url like "http:abc.com" in all pages. what ever it may the action and view i require fixed url for my app. can we use files in mvc or routing to achieve this?

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: What you ask isn't URL rewriting. It's the job of IIS and DNS, not ASP.NET MVC. If you use `http:abc.com` your browser will ask *DNS* to find out which server to call. Since you didn't mention ASP.NET Core, that server is IIS. It's *IIS* that's going to map the call to your web application and finally call it, passing the URL to it

Comment: If you want to test your application using a "real" URL you can add an entry to your `hosts` file that maps the domain part to your local machine or to your development server's IP. If you have multiple web applications on IIS but want your test application to listen to port 80, you can [use host headers](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO20113.html) to make IIS map that domain name to a web site.

Comment: [This ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/677403/setting-up-a-domain-name-to-use-host-headers) article explains why host headers work. The browser makes a call to the IP returned by DNS and sends the *relative* URL and domain name in the request. The domain name is passed in the `host` header